# Rewrite.log over 40G in Linux tmp folder

Tags: linux, tmp

We are trying to cut back some space on our linux-based server and noticed that within ./tmp there is a file called rewrite.log that is 41G. I'm not entirely sure if I can delete this file, or how/if I can downsize it.

Thank you,

Brandon

Comment: That's probably overly verbose logging from mod_rewrite. I'd nuke the log and tone down the amount of logging it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a log file created by the Apache HTTPD server. [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) is what is creating it. You could safely delete it, or just change the LogLevel in your httpd.conf so that it does not output as much info. If I were you, I would 1) stop the HTTPD server, 2) delete the log file, 3) edit the httpd.conf file and set `LogLevel` to `warn` and 4) start the HTTPD server.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @OHairBear If my answer is the correct answer, you should accept it. While you are logged in, click the checkmark by my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn off [`RewriteLog`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritelog).

Comment: Better idea, RewriteLog would be better to turn off then LogLevel.